# What are the (dis)advantages of moving the entire lens for focusing vs. only parts of it?

Tags: autofocus, optics, lens-design, lens-adapter, focus-motor

There's a lens adapter available that adapts Leica lenses to Sony mirrorless cameras. It's called TECHART PRO. The key feature is that it allows to use autofocus with the manual lenses.

This works by moving the entire lens back and forth and is advertised to work for most lenses. Most lenses achieve focus by moving a few lens elements, but not the entire lens.

Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/75800/49477

Comment: Historical note: when Nikon made the switch to AF, they had a teleconverter that did the same thing to allow AF with MF lenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disadvantages, well speed and potentially (depending on the distance needed) the TECHART PRO may run out of space making some lenses focus extremities unavailable.
Larger heavier lenses may be to heavier for the focus as well.

Overall however it's a very interesting concept, with very few real downsides.